# In SQL How is it possible to use the Sum Function in an Update

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum, sql-update

This is the code that i used

```
UPDATE Customers c   
SET c.TotalP= 
   (SELECT SUM(b.Price) 
    FROM Products b
   WHERE b.CustomerID= c.CustomerID)
```

I im trying to set a value x to the TotalP field in the Customers table.
The value x is equal to the sum of the coressponding prices in the Products table where the Customer ID's are the same.

The above code returns an error of `"Operation must be an Updateable query"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use DSum:

```
UPDATE Customers   
SET TotalP = DSum("Price","Products","CustomerID = " & CustomerID)
```

But it does raise the question as to why you are updating a table with a calculated value when the information can be obtained from a query.

Comment: The above code returns the fields empty, What im trying to do is to get the sum of the values from the products table and put that in the customers table. What im trying to do is for a project at school display the data using a Jtable in Java, This is the last concept i must add to the program. then im finished.

Comment: Is it possible to Upload the database?

Comment: Not really, you could use dropbox or such like. Have you tried running the query in MS Access? Do you get any errors?

Comment: I tried this solution in Access 2007 and it updates the customer table with the sum of prices with like CustomerID in Products. Perhaps you can show the table definitions for the relevant fields.

Comment: I am running the query in Access, that's where it field returns null.

Comment: Is it possible to send the database to anyone?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the relationship between the tables, is one to many(Customers 1:Products Many) according to the CustomerID

Comment: Post your table definitions as @rontornambe says. The SQL above is pretty standard for MS Access and works with 1->Many perfectly well.

Comment: For example: CustID Integer, primary key; CustomerName, Text; DateJoined, Date. You can even just post a few rows from each table.

Comment: Thanks for the Help I just played around with the DSUM until I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from VBA scripting, Microsoft has three methods:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/116142

The following are two SQL statements for updating one record at a time using a cross-join:

```
UPDATE tmp SET tmp.non_null_cnt = 0;

UPDATE tmp, ESC_Results SET tmp.non_null_cnt = [tmp].[non_null_cnt]+1
WHERE ESC_Results.asset4_id Is Not Null;
```

It will be slower than the other methods because it has to re-calculate the sum for every row stored.