# Sum and Update tables in access sql query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I m trying to sum a column of a certain criteria in a table and update these values to another table. here is what i have so far

```
UPDATE table2 SET table2.column2 = (SELECT Sum([oldtable].values) AS sumvalues 
FROM [oldtable] 
WHERE ((([oldtable].types)= category1 )) 
);
```

so im trying to get the Sum of the values in the values column of "oldtable" where the criteria in the types column is category1

but i get this error when i execute this code "Operation must use updatable query"

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203094/in-sql-how-is-it-possible-to-use-the-sum-function-in-an-update

Comment: There are probably hundreds of questions that address this very topic. Do a search for "Operation must use updatable query".